# jQuery Clone / Copy Style attributes of first td of Table to another Tables's first td

Tags: jquery

I have 2 tables.. namely **`table-1`** and **`table-2`**...

First **`<td>`** of **`table-1`** has style attribute which is setting up dynamically.

How can I clone/copy all the style attributes from first td of **`table-1`** and apply to **`table-2`** of first td?

[Online Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYLBNb)

Please refer below screenshot for the explanation...

[image]

**HTML**

```
<h2>Table - 1</h2>
<table class="table table-bordered" id="table-1">
  <tr>
    <td style="background:#ccc;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;color:red;">T1 - R1 - Column 01</td>
    <td>T1 - R1 - Column 02</td>
    <td>T1 - R1 - Column 03</td>
    <td>T1 - R1 - Column 04</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<h2>Table - 2</h2>
<table class="table table-bordered" id="table-2">
  <tr>
    <td>T2 - R1 - Column 01</td>
    <td>T2 - R1 - Column 02</td>
    <td>T2 - R1 - Column 03</td>
    <td>T2 - R1 - Column 04</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery**

```
var x = $('#table-1 tr td:first').clone().attr('style', '');
$('#table-2 tr td:first').attr('style', x)
```

Comment: You should strive to have your styling in CSS classes and not hard-coded in your markup. Then it will be easier to "copy" styles or just set a proper selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like this [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MaRMpX)

**JS:**

```
var x = $('#table-1 tr td:first').clone().attr('style');
$('#table-2 tr td:first').attr('style', x)
```

the `.attr('foo')` will **get** the value of the `foo` attribute, while `.attr('foo', 'bar');`will **set** the value `bar` to the attribute `foo`

Comment: **@Mi-Creativity**, Thanks for correcting me... It is working as expected

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:**

You set all styles of cloned element  to `''`. It means all style is removed. In addintion, For getting style an element, you have to use [`.attr('attributeName')`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName).

```
var x = $('#table-1 tr td:first').clone().attr('style');
$('#table-2 tr td:first').attr('style', x);
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjBXea)

Comment: **@alireza safian** yes... I just now realized the issue.. Thanks for correcting me...

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#table-2 tr:first td:first').attr('style', $('#table-1 tr:first td:first').attr('style'))
```

The above will take the style attribute of the first cell in the first row of `#table-1` and apply it to the first cell in the first row of `table-2`